# How to have dynamically the environment value in each environment of Synapse?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse

In Azure I work with Azure Synapse Analytics. I have a Synapse Analytics by environment. Once I have finished my pipeline in development environment I have a release pipeline in devops that deploy to preprod env.

Problem is that in my notebooks I have the following parameter : "env" used in this path `path = f'abfss://bronze@synapse{env}.dfs.core.windows.net'`

Parameter env is in a json that I give in the Parameters tab in Synapse.

My pipeline in preprod fail because in notebook the path is `path = f'abfss://bronze@synapsedev.dfs.core.windows.net'

How can I do to dynamically have the env value in each environment ? I don't want to change it manually because there is a release pipeline in devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mssparkutils to get the name of the current environment, instead of pooling it from a parameter:

```
mssparkutils.env.getWorkspaceName()
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python#environment-utilities

Comment: And is it a good idea to modify the value in release pipeline, in a command line task for example ? Json file that correspond to my synapse pipeline is in the devops repos.

Comment: @codelifevcd If you use the approach above you don't need to change anything when moving environment. On other cases, like using resources with different names on each environment, you need to change in the devops pipeline.

Comment: That's only part of the solution as it does assume that the workspace and default storage account share a name.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer does help I would argue it is not a solution as it assumes that the storage account which is the default storage is named the same as the synapse workspace. I have worked in a lot of environments where customers have strict naming conventions and as such there are weird and wonderful names for storage accounts that differ from the workspace. As such, can I offer a similar - but in my view better - solution:

```
import json 
linked_service = json.loads(
TokenLibrary.getPropertiesAll(
    f'{mssparkutils.env.getWorkspaceName()}-WorkspaceDefaultStorage'
    )
)
storage_account = linked_service['Endpoint']\
                .replace('https://','')\
                .replace('.dfs.core.windows.net', '')
```